# Different font for list numbers and list contents

Tags: css

In CSS, I am trying to style an ordered list so that the contents are one font, but the the numbers are another font. 
How can I target the list-numbers, which aren't html elements and part of the list-style ?

The only thing that I can think of and have tried is making the list an unordered list. Setting the list-style to none and then manually having numbers inside the list that are wrapped in 's where I style them differently. 
But that seems highly inefficient.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: I'd start by looking here: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/style-your-ordered-list

Comment: @j08691 I just edited the question with a description of what I've tried.

Comment: Probably the easiest solution would be to set a style on the list and then wrap your list elements with spans and then target them with a different style.

Comment: You could also try something similar to http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201105/styling_ordered_list_numbers/

Comment: @j08691 good idea, someone posted that as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML

```
<ol>
    <li><p>Hello</p></li>
    <li><p>World</p></li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
ol{
    font: italic 1em Georgia, Times, serif;
}

ol p{
    font: normal .8em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pLPUb/) of the example above